# Copy a file to a directory that doesn't exist with only one command (Linux)

Tags: shell

Is it possible to copy a file to a dir that doesn't exist such that it creates the directory, using only one command? Without using `&&` and more than one command.

Edit:
It is not duplicate, in the other ask the answer is a function, I ask about a command, only one command, without &&, functions, |, etc. It is a question for learn more and for know if exist commands that do it, because cp don't. Is a question for explain it in a high school.

Comment: I explain why is not duplicate and why I ask it. I don't think that don't know why I ask is reason for donwvoting, but I already say it. In other question the result is same, but question is not same.

Comment: @JHG: Agreed. I think peterph explained the value of this question, upvoting, and the *duplicate* question indeed doesn't contain some of the answers and especially not the accepted one. This question and its answers stand on its own.