# How use `rsync -R` with multiple subdirs or install -D with multiple files?

Tags: shell, rsync, cp

Is possible with `rsync` to copy multiple files from a source directory to a dest directory with multiple subdirectories that don't exist? Or use `install -D` with multiples files to a directory that doesn't exist?

Also I looked at `cp --parents` but used the name of the source directory. Is it possible that `cp` can select a destination directory that doesn't exist and copy all files to it after it makes it?

I have this question: [Copy a file to a directory that doesn't exist with only one command (Linux)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128180/copy-a-file-to-a-directory-that-doesnt-exist-with-only-one-command-linux)
Merge with: [How can I copy a file and create the target directories at the same time?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41770/how-can-i-copy-a-file-and-create-the-target-directories-at-the-same-time)

But the solutions for copying one file, I looking at something like:

```
cp /etc/*.conf ~/mytest/
```

where mytest doesn't exist and `/etc/*.conf` is more than one file. Is it possible with `cp` and with only one command is better?

Answer (score 1):

Try with `rsync` command:

```
rsync -av /etc/*.conf ~/mytest
```

---

In general you can use

```
rsync -av In/*conf Out/NewDir
```

The situation before is:

```
In
├── d1.conf
├── d2.conf
├── d3.txt
├── Sub_In_1
└── Sub_In_2.conf
    └── SubIn2.Files

Out
└── Out_OldFiles
```

After the command will be

```
Out
├── NewDir
│   ├── d1.conf
│   ├── d2.conf
│   └── Sub_In_2.conf
│       └── SubIn2.Files
└── Out_OldFiles
```

In this case you select not only common files `*.conf` but even directory `Sub_In_2.conf`. You will copy all the selection (files and directory) in a newly created directory `NewDir` below the `Out` directory.

The option `-a` include even the -r one (recurse into directories)

```
  -a, --archive               archive mode; equals -rlptgoD (no -H,-A,-X)
```

**Notes**

- The `rsync` recursive option is **-r** (and not **-R**).
- In `cp` -r and -R correspond to the same option.
- The option `-v` is not necessary it gives only some info more.
- With`rsync` you can be used even between 2 different computer
  using `host1` for the origin host and `host2` for the destination host.

The last command is

```
rsync  -av host1:InputDir host2:OutputDir/NewDirThatDidNotExists
```

Comment: This should be an edit to your exisiting answer...

Comment: I start to answer before you modify and clarify the question. Now it is more clear, before it should be one of the 2 cases (slightly different)... More practical examples can help different people maybe...

Comment: Compacted the answer is one. @jasonwryan Check if it's better now. For JHG Does it solve?